# Count number of child nodes of a sibling in XSLT

Tags: xslt, siblings

I need to be able to count how many child nodes the sibling element has.  I need to change the CSS class to be "no_border" on an anchor tag based upon whether the next anchor tag has any child nodes.

What I have so far is like this :

```
<xsl:for-each select="Menu/Item">
  <li>
    <a>
      <xsl:attribute name="class">
        <xsl:if test="following-sibling::Item/count(Menu/Item)">
          no_border
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:value-of select="ItemTitle />
    </a>
   </li>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Visual Studio is telling me :

> Error  1   Expected end of the expression, found '('.  following-sibling::Item/count -->(<-- Menu/Item)    C:\Projects***\XmlFiles\xslt\SiteMap.xslt  78  74  C:\Projects***\

So it looks like I can't put the "count()" command after "following-sibling".

Here is a sample of the XML:

```
<root>
  <Item>
    <Menu>
      <Item>
      ... other sub-nodes
      </Item>
    </Menu>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Menu>
      <Item>
      ... other sub-nodes
      </Item>
    </Menu>
  </Item>
</root>
```

Edit: I found the solution:

```
<xsl:if test="count(following-sibling::Item/Menu/Item) = 0" >
```

Comment: Your original code is legal in XSLT 2.0 but not in XSLT 1.0. For future reference, please make it clear which version you are using.

Comment: @user709466: Answers should be on their own. This is not a real question as is.

Comment: +1 for the question, but please post an answer with your latest edit, and accept it: so everyone will see this thread has a solution.

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer, i didnt want to search for ages for this :)